# jQueryUI icons do not center when rendered inside Menu Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

Can I fix these buttons so the icons center inside them? This only occurs inside a Menu widget. In my screenshot, you can see how they are aligned top left to the buttons. I have one button outside the menu as an example of it working there. The code creating the buttons is the same. jQuery 1.8.2 and jQueryUI 1.9.0

```
        $(".save").button({
            text: false,
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-disk" }
        }).click(function () { alert('Save not implemented yet'); return false; });

        $(".Delete").button({
            text: false,
            icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash" }
        }).click(function () { alert('Delete not implemented yet'); return false; });
```

[image: screenshot of jQueryUI menu widget and mis-rendered icons]

Comment: use a console to inspect the css and adjust accordingly. Can't troubleshoot css from an image

Comment: If I remove the top and left from the jQuery css file for .ui-menu .ui-icon it resolves the problem. I'm not a fan of modifying these files. I tried override it in my html file but no luck.             .ui-menu .ui-icon{position:absolute;top:.2em;left:.2em}

Comment: you can leave the original files alone, and simply write a more specific css rule that will outrank the original, or use `!important` or just make sure new rules load after main UI css css file